# Change href in div to normal text

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have one problem. On my website, I have `<div id="alpha_bravo">`, with links inside. It looks like this:

```
<div id="alpha_bravo">
  <p>text text text <a href="...">link</a></p>
</div>
```

I want change every `<a href...>` to funny text like `suprise`, as an example.

How can I do it?

Comment: `<div id"alpha_bravo">` if that's your real code, it's missing an equal sign.

Comment: No this is my mistake, my html on website is 100% correct. I just want change every links only in this one div alpha_bravo

Comment: Do you want to replace "a href" to "surprise" or  value of href to surprise. Can you provide sample output?

Comment: @akmnahid i just want destroy thats links beacuse people put there very dangerous links.

Comment: you want to do this on the server or client side? using which language? php/js?

Comment: i try do it in css as visibility:hidden but it doesn't work, beacause it is still in page source. I wan't delete it on the page source, but idk how beacause i'n noob.

Comment: @Agnees is this data coming from a database?

Comment: @dchayka yes, of course. Now i have `<script>
$(".zmiana_linkow:contains('href')").text('Connect');
</script>` but it works only for one link. When i have more links it isn;t work

Comment: I fixed the grammar a bit and made it slightly more clear. You should still show exactly what input and output you expect, because I'm still unclear whether you want to replace the entire `<a href="...">link</a>` or just `a href`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with PHP and from the comments below the question it seems that you may want to use server-side functionality, I'm going to give an example using PHP.

One way is to replace only links. You are looking for [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function that will replace all substrings in the string based on a regex pattern.

```
$input = "<div id='alpha_bravo'><p>text text text <a href='...'>link</a> and <a href='...'>another link</a></p></div>";
$output = preg_replace("/<a (.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i", "surprise", $input);
```

You can also just remove all HTML tags in the string using [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
$input = "<div id='alpha_bravo'><p>text text text <a href='...'>link</a> and <a href='...'>another link</a></p></div>";
$output = strip_tags($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is coming from a database, first word of advice is that you filter your input before saving it in database.

Secondly, if you don't want those links to render and replace them with some other value then use PHP's function `preg_replace()` as already mentioned by PetrHejda..

PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Your `<a ...>...</a>` pattern may differ if users insert styling and classes. 
Try using this pattern as your solution: `preg_replace("/<a(.+?)href=\"(.+?)\"/", "<a$1href=\"your_value_here\"", $yourStringHere);`

You may use `g` or `i` flags. Start here with regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.